# How to get permanent Facebook access token now that app's are not being reviewed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Apps are no longer being reviewed, but I need a permanent access token for a current project.

Does anyone know how to extend the access token.  The current "extend access token" button that extends the token by 60 days results in this error.  As does any request with an "unverified" app id.

```
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook:

> "Beginning April 4, 2018, all apps, including those formerly approved,
>   must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the Events API,
>   Groups API, and Pages API. Apps accessing the Events API and Groups
>   API will lose access and require review once App Review resumes. For
>   apps using Pages API, review will be required once App Review resumes
>   or access will be removed."

You can read more about it here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes/?translation&hc_location=ufi#groups-4-4

Regarding the error that you receive, I currently have two applications. One which I've been using regularly and one that I haven't used for the past 6 months. 
If I send a request to extend my token for the latter one, I receive the same error (which makes sense according to the error message), but if I send a request with the first one, I am able to extend the access token and get the expected response.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is helpful.  But when I login to the dev portal there is a banner at the top saying "No apps are being reviewed at this time".  I have not found any information stating how long this "freeze" will last.

Answer (score 0):

Please update us, once the problem is getting solved, let me know how much time Facebook team is taking to review.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your post does not contain an answer to the question. If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.